# Undefined namespace prefix 'jbdc'

Tags: xslt, integration, xslt-2.0, sapb1

**Hi guys,**

I'm trying create a webservice with SAP B1if whatching that tutorial:
Part1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9hLVwJDEz4

In part 4 at minute 7:23 the guy wrote a part of xsl on document and he saved, when i go save i have next error: "*Undefined namespace prefix 'jbdc'*"

Printscreen of the error:
[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "jbdc" to "jdbc" in your code.
jdbc stands for Java Database Connectivity